# Python CSV - use dictionary for each cell

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, cell

i hope my question makes sense. i am looking for a way to read a csv file, and map a dictionary to each cell. i can make it work without csv, but i am having a hard time making it work when reading a csv file.

note:

```
string0 would be cell A1 or row[0] 
string1 would be cell B1 or row[1] 
string2 would be cell C1 or row[2]
```

this is what i have so far:

```
dict0 = {'A':'CODE1', 'B':'CODE2'}
text0 = []
string0 = 'A'

dict1 = {'avenue':'ave', 'street':'st', 'road':'rd', 'court':'ct'}
text1 = []
string1 = '123 MAIN AVENUE'

dict2 = {'(':'', ')':'', '-':'', ' ':'', '/':'', '\\':''}
text2 = []
string2 = '(123) 456/7890'


for i in string0:
    newcode = dict0.get(i,i)
    text0.append(newcode)
print ' '.join(text0)


for i in string1.lower().split(' '):
    newaddress = dict1.get(i.lower(),i)
    text1.append(newaddress)
print ' '.join(text1)


for i in string2:
    newphone = dict2.get(i,i)
    text2.append(newphone)
print ''.join(text2)
```

the code above works exactly as i intend it to work, but im having a hard time trying to make it work when reading a csv file.

thank you very much

edit #1:***************************************************

here is an excerpt of sample1.csv:

```
A,123 MAIN STREET,(123) 456-7890
B,888 TEST ROAD,(222) 555-5555
```

sorry if the code isnt much cleaner/clearer, but that is why i am asking for guidance.

in essence, every column will have a dictionary associated with it, so that the "code" column will write "CODE1 or CODE2" depending on the value of cell A1 ("A" or "B").

column 2 will have dict1{} associated with it, and will clean up the address column.
column 3 will have dict2{} associated with it, and will remove (,),/,\ from the phone number column.

my issue is i do not know how to start the code. i can write the code if i set the cell information as variables (see me code above, variables: string0, string1, string2), but i do not know how i would start to iterate the csv file.

thank you

edit #2:***************************************************

here is my code when i try using `import csv`

```
dict0 = {'A':'CODE1', 'B':'CODE2'}
text0 = []
dict1 = {'avenue':'ave', 'street':'st', 'road':'rd', 'court':'ct'}
text1 = []
dict2 = {'(':'', ')':'', '-':'', ' ':'', '/':'', '\\':''}
text2 = []

import csv

with open('O:/sample1.csv', 'rb') as c:
    reader = csv.reader(c)

    for row in reader:

        for i in row[0]:
            newcode = dict0.get(i,i)
            text0.append(newcode)


        for i in row[1].lower().split(' '):
            newaddress = dict1.get(i.lower(),i)
            text1.append(newaddress)


        for i in row[2]:
            newphone = dict2.get(i,i)
            text2.append(newphone)


        print str(' '.join(text0)) + ',' + str(' '.join(text1)) + ',' + str(''.join(text2))
```

prints:

```
CODE1,123 main st,1234567890
CODE1 CODE2,123 main st 888 test rd,12345678902225555555
```

i would like to print:

```
CODE1,123 main st,1234567890
CODE2,888 test rd,2225555555
```

hopefully someone can help

thank you

edit #3 *************************************************************************************************************************

can the following be improved (syntax, indentation etc..):

sample1.csv:

```
A,123 MAIN STREET,(123) 456-7890
B,888 TEST ROAD,(222) 555-5555
```

here is the code:

```
import csv

newcsv = csv.writer(open('O:/csvfile1.csv', 'ab'))

with open('O:/sample1.csv', 'rb') as c:
    reader = csv.reader(c)

    dict0 = {'A':'CODE1', 'B':'CODE2'}
    dict1 = {'avenue':'ave', 'street':'st', 'road':'rd', 'court':'ct'}
    dict2 = {'(':'', ')':'', '-':'', ' ':'', '/':'', '\\':''}

    # read element in *reader*
    for row in reader:
        text0 = []
        text1 = []
        text2 = []
        newline = []

        # read element in *row*
        for i in row[0]:
            newcode = dict0.get(i,i)
            text0.append(newcode)
        newline.append(' '.join(text0))

        for i in row[1].lower().split(' '):
            newaddress = dict1.get(i.lower(),i)
            text1.append(newaddress)
        newline.append(' '.join(text1))

        for i in row[2]:
            newphone = dict2.get(i,i)
            text2.append(newphone)
        newline.append(''.join(text2))


        newcsv.writerow(newline)

        print newline
```

prints the following:

```
['CODE1', '123 main st', '1234567890']
['CODE2', '888 test rd', '2225555555']
```

creates csvfile1.csv (using '|' as a 'cell delimiter') and its exactly what i want:

```
CODE1|123 main st|1234567890
CODE2|888 test rd|2225555555
```

just wondering if the above code can be improved/written in an more effective way.

thank you

Comment: Could you please add an excerpt from the `sample1.csv`? At least the first couple of rows...

Comment: It unclear what the code you have does, in so far as how it relates to creating a dictionary for each cell. Please elaborate and show sample input and output.

Comment: ok, i added an excerpt from sample1.csv and i tried to further explain my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the garbled output is that you are not clearing the `text<n>` variables on each cycle of the loop. While there is the fix below, I recommend reading at least [how to define functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), rewriting the code without so many global variables so that you don't run into the same problems like now.

```
with open('O:/sample1.csv', 'rb') as c:
reader = csv.reader(c)

for row in reader:
    text0 = []
    text1 = []
    text2 = []
    for i in row[0]:
        newcode = dict0.get(i,i)
        text0.append(newcode)


    for i in row[1].lower().split(' '):
        newaddress = dict1.get(i.lower(),i)
        text1.append(newaddress)


    for i in row[2]:
        newphone = dict2.get(i,i)
        text2.append(newphone)


    print str(' '.join(text0)) + ',' + str(' '.join(text1)) + ',' + str(''.join(text2))
```

Comment: do you think the code i posted (edit # 3) can be improved? if so can you provide some pointers/tips as to how?